# Write to file not working (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, file

I am starting learning about Swift programming. Up to now, I have already developed my first working app. Although simple, it is a very useful one. But with the introduction of Swift 4 and XCode 9, I'm facing some headaches. Right now I am trying to write a small piece of code to write a string to a file, like this:

```
let fileName = "myFile.txt"
let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: 
NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
var myText = "Some text to write to file"
do {
    try myText.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: UTF8)
} catch {
    // Handle error
}
```

When I write myText.write, XCode suggests the above syntax, but right after I choose it and fill the placeholders, XCode displays the error "Extra argument 'atomically' in call. Note that it is the very structure it suggested. I haven't found any workaround until now. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is misleading. The encoding parameter is wrong

```
try myText.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
```

And don't use `NSURL` in Swift 3+, use native `URL`:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: ...
```

---

However I recommend this way

```
let fileName = "myFile.txt"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
let myText = "Some text to write to file"
let data = Data(myText.utf8)
do {
    try data.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @vadian. Your solution worked fine. As you said, it is really misleading. The "write to URL" code I was trying is in Apple Developer's documentation and was also suggested by XCode. Too bad it was flagged as error by the compiler.